# Exit Java application even if a dialog is open

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

In my application, I use a dialog form:

```
UtilisateursDialog dialog = new UtilisateursDialog(this,true);
presenter.setUtilisateurActif(dialog.showDialog());
```

Where UtilisateursDialog is a swing.JDialog.

When the dialog is visible, I noticed that it is impossible to exit the application. In MacOS, a click on application/quit or option+Q do nothing.

Is there a way to make the user able to exit when the dialog is visible?

Comment: The user can always force-quit the application...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the dialog to be modal, do `presenter.setModal(false)` before showing it and the menubar will become functional again.

Answer (score 2):

Give a button in dialog with `System.exit(0);` in its action performed,Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine.  :)

Comment: I guess System.exit(0) completly shutdown JVM which may terminate all applications on that JVM, not only the application OP was referring isn't it? Is it safe to do it here?

Comment: @thinksteep I mentioned it will terminate the current JVM :) if this is not what he need, let him respond :) but I guess this is the best way to exit the application.

Comment: Ok with this solution, but it's not what I'm looking for. I want the menu/quit to be available when a dialog is showed

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem at all.  The question wasn't how to exit the application, but how to exit the application from the menu.

Comment: @JayAskren the question is : s there a way to make the user able to exit when the dialog is visible?, and I mentioned about adding a button to the dialog :) how is that not possible?

Comment: The question explictly says "a click on application/quit or option+Q do nothing."